# Trying to transform list in pandas Dataframe but get unexpected output while having text inside list

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to transform list in pandas Dataframe but get unexpected output

````py
import pandas as pd  
reader=pd.read_csv("txt",sep='\t',chunksize=500)  
sl=[]  
for chunk in reader:  
    sl.append(chunk)
    break

pd.DataFrame(sl)# Trying to conver into DF```


Output:
   0
0 norm...
````

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over `reader` is returning `DataFrame`s in `chunk`.  So, you need to access the `values` in each `chunk` `DataFrame`.  The following shows loading the csv incrementally, and placing its data into a list which is then used to reconstitute it as a `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = """ID,week,sale
A,1,1
A,2,4
A,3,10
B,1,7
B,2,2.3
B,3,4.4"""

with open('txt.csv', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(csvdata)

reader=pd.read_csv('txt.csv', chunksize=2)

sl=[]
for chunk in reader:
    # each chunk is a DataFrame
    print("Chunk type {}".format(type(chunk)))
    print("Chunk values {}".format(chunk.values))
    for row in chunk.values:
        sl.append(row)
print(sl)

df = pd.DataFrame(sl)
print(df)
```

Comment: You are welcome.  You may wish to update your Q title to, "read_csv with chunksize creates unexpected output" to help future Stack Overflow pandas users looking to do something similar.  And then you can accept this answer as the correct one to further provide guidance and make the community a great place.